# Typescript Error on compile last jquery declaration file: jquery.d.ts (164,59): Expected '{'

Tags: jquery, typescript, tsc

I integrated jquery.d.ts by using "tsd".
But while try to compile it:

```
tsc typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts
```

I got the follwing error:

```
typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts (164,59): Expected '{'
```

jquery.d.ts Line: 164

```
interface JQueryXHR extends XMLHttpRequest, JQueryPromise<any> {
```

Installed versions:

```
Typescript: 0.9.5
NPM: 1.3.4
NODE: 0.10.25
```

I figured out that if a change the line to the follwing:

```
interface JQueryXHR extends XMLHttpRequest, JQueryPromise {
```

this error will not be thrown anymore on this line but on the next on.
So it seems to me, that the compiler does not support any definitions like:

```
SomeType<T>
```

Does I use the wrong typescript version? I used npm to install this one and it seems to be the newest one.

I'm new to typescript - so has anybody a hint for me?

**Found the issue: in system path an old version of tsc was registered. I added correct path to tsc binary and everything works fine.**

Comment: Odd -- I don't see that error when compiling. (It's just a definition  file though ... so you shouldn't need to compile it.). Confirm current installation: `npm install -g --force typescript`.

Comment: Installation confirmed - nothing changed. ( Sure i did not need to compile it to get all running - but using it with PHPStorm will show this error every time a *.ts file changed )

Comment: does PHPStorm have it's own copy of TypeScript it's using? Have you checked the file watcher settings?

Comment: Checked: It uses the system installation ( /usr/local/bin/tsc ) - it does not matter if i call it from console or in PHPStorm the error is the same

Comment: mm cracy -v / --version got 'Unknown option'; --help show no version

Comment: just `tsc` then? I think you're using an older version, as `--version` or `-v` should work.

Comment: Thx - I figured out and updated the question ...

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because [generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics) (`SomeType<T>`) are fully supported since version 1.0.

> Generics has been the most highly requested feature over the last 6 month, and has always been something we planned to include in TypeScript 1.0. -- Luke Hoban [MS], 25 Mar 2013 ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/03/25/working-on-typescript-0-9-generics-overload-on-constants-and-compiler-performance.aspx))

However, as far as I remember I used generics in older version than 0.9.5. It means you could have corrupted installation.

For Windows:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\`
2. See what versions you have there.
3. Verify version in properties of file `...\0.9\tsc.exe`.
4. If you have more versions there, verify `%PATH%` variable:

   - Run command line and type `echo %PATH%`
   - Look for "typescript", it could be there more times, it could be missing or there could be wrong version.

For linux based systems the approach will be similar but without "Program Files". ;)